# A script to export org with highlighted code block

Tags: org-export, syntax-highlighting, htmlize, tree-sitter

I've written the script to export all of my ORG files into HTML files.  It takes the files from the folder "content" and saves the results to "public".

```lisp
(setq user-emacs-directory "./.packages")
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
(straight-use-package 'use-package)
(setq-default use-package-always-defer t)

(use-package htmlize
   :straight t)

(use-package tree-sitter-langs
  :straight t)

(global-tree-sitter-mode)
(setq org-html-validation-link nil)
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      (list
       (list "org-site:main"
             :recursive t
             :base-directory "./content"
             :publishing-function 'org-html-publish-to-html
             :publishing-directory "./public"
             :with-author nil           ;; Don't include author name
             :with-creator nil            ;; Include Emacs and Org versions in footer
             :with-toc nil                ;; Include a table of contents
             :section-numbers nil       ;; Don't include section numbers
             :time-stamp-file nil)))    ;; Don't include time stamp in file

;; Generate the site output
(org-publish-all t)
```

The problem is that I don't get the syntax highlight in the source code blocks when I run the script as an Emacs Lisp script: `emacs -Q --script init.el`. I get the syntax highlighting in the source code blocks when I run Emacs and load the file: `emacs -Q  -l init.el`.

An example of an org file from the directory

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  def hello(name):
      return f"hello {name}"

  hello("world")
#+END_SRC
```

How do I get the syntax highlight running the file as an Emacs Lisp script?

GNU Emacs 28.3